# Redecorate ILightweightLabelDecorator

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a working `ILightweightLabelDecorator` that happily decorates some kind of object in my tree. Now that object changes, and I want to trigger a refresh / redecoration.

I found [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html) (under "Re-decorate") which wants me to call
`LabelProvider#fireLabelProviderChanged()`. The problem is: the method in question is a protected one and the place where the object changes is nowhere near the label decorator.

Let's say for the sake of simplicity I have the following method on my `IViewPart`:

```
public void refresh() {
    this.treeViewer.refresh();
}
```

How would I trigger the redecoration of my viewer elements there?

Comment: Are you using `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingLabelProvider`?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I am.

Comment: I think that is supposed to deal with updating the decorators on `refresh` calls automatically.

Comment: I haven't verified programmatically but digging through jface code, i think treeViewer.refresh(Boolean updateLabels) should trigger decorators

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to tell the decorator manager to update decoration for a particular decorator id:

```
IDecoratorManager decoratorManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();

decoratorManager.update("decorator id");
```

(must be run in the UI thread).

Comment: The view in question does not know the IDs of all the decorators that are / could be registered for it's elements.